# Loading a Form without Calling Form.resize()?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a question regarding the form load and form resize. I have 2 forms, lets call them form1 and form2.

In form1, I want to fire only the load event of the form.

In VB6, it is just easy just call "load + form1" then that is it but how about on VB.NET?

My main problem here is I just want to run/trigger first the FORM LOAD before FORM RESIZE trigger.

Comment: The simple way is to use a variable of type Boolean that you test in the Resize event handler and set to True whenever it should do something.  The proper way is to only subscribe the event when you are ready for it to be fired.  Exactly what kind of help you need to do this the simple or proper way is very unclear.  Always post at least an attempt at making this work yourself so we can tell.

Comment: Hi @HansPassant, I guess the simple way will work, thanks for that. But I want to give a try to the PROPER WAY.. How can i achieve "to subscribe only to the event of the form?"

Answer (score 0):

You can't just fire the load event. The same is true of VB6.

The equivalebt of VB6 `Load Form1` in VB.NET is `Form1.Show`

This will fire the following events in this order:

```
Form.Load
Form.Activated
Form.Shown
```

What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to achieve, only trigger the load event of the form not the resize event. only the form load.. thanks for the quick response sir Matt :))